# Problems sorting by date

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, datetime

I'm attempting to only display data added to my database 24 hours ago or less. However, for some reason, the code I've written isn't working, and both entries in my database, one from 1 hour ago, one from 2 days ago, show up. Is there something wrong with my equation? Thanks!

```
public void UpdateValues()
    {
        double TotalCost = 0;
        double TotalEarned = 0;
        double TotalProfit = 0;
        double TotalHST = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Program.TransactionList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime Jan2013 = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2013"); //Hours since Jan12013
            int TodayHoursSince2013 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Today.Subtract(Jan2013).TotalHours)); //7
            int ItemHoursSince2013 = Program.TransactionList[i].HoursSince2013; //Equals 7176, and 7130

            if (ItemHoursSince2013 - TodayHoursSince2013 <= 24)
            {
                TotalCost += Program.TransactionList[i].TotalCost;
                TotalEarned += Program.TransactionList[i].TotalEarned;
                TotalProfit += Program.TransactionList[i].TotalEarned - Program.TransactionList[i].TotalCost;
                TotalHST += Program.TransactionList[i].TotalHST;
            }
        }
        label6.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalCost);
        label7.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalEarned);
        label8.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalProfit);
        label10.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalHST);
    }
```

Comment: your datatime values from database are in  Program.TransactionList?...like  Program.TransactionList[i].mydatetime for example?

Comment: `Program.TransactionList[i].HoursSince2013` is added like this:
`...HoursSince2013 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(TimeSince2013.TotalHours)),...  `

Comment: why aren't you just storing a real DateTime in the DB? Would be much easier

Comment: Ok, I'm now storing a DateTime in my database. Still can't get the 24 hours thing to work properly though.

Comment: Got it, I used some code from an answer that's now deleted... Thanks mystery person!

Comment: if you are storing as datetime then check my answer please.Lol its my answer i am mystery guy :)i deleted it as i was editing to fit the hours you were storing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place it inside your for loop(the datetime variable now place it outside):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime TransactionListDate = Program.TransactionList[i].HoursSince2013;
if (TransactionListDate > now.AddHours(-24) && TransactionListDate <= now)
{
    //it falls between now and last 24 hours....
}
```

I think this is what you need.I assume Program.TransactionList[i].HoursSince2013 is the datetime.